# Open an application in Mac using command line and keep it active window

Tags: macos, terminal

I can use following code in `Terminal` to open an application e.g. `Safari`

```
open -a Safari
```

However sometimes if there are multiple such lines, then a desired application moves out of focus and becomes inactive window.

Is there any way to keep a particular newly opened Application in focus and keep it active application?

My above example is with `Safari`, however I am looking a generic approach that can be applied to any application in Mac which I can open using `open` commend in `Terminal`.

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use applescript to activate Safari:

```
open -a Safari
open -a "Other application"
...
osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to activate'
```

Comment: Should this be the full code : `open -a Safari && osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to activate'`?